# Running DotNet Build Causes Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll Assembly Conflict

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, build-automation, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm having an issue trying to build a dotnet core project from command line that has these references:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.6.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" Version="2.6.1" />
```

For whatever reason it keeps saying `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll` assembly has already been loaded. Here is the exact error message:

> C:\Users.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.compilers\2.6.1\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5):
>   error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could
>   not be loaded from the assembly
>
> C:\Users.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.compilers\2.6.1\build..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll.
>   Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the 
>   declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
>   available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

When I go to that project directory and run `dotnet build` It has no issues building the project, but when I run dotnet build against the solution that's when I get this error. If I build the solution from Visual Studio it also has no issues building. Really strange behavior, not quite sure how to get around it.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696012/microsoft-codeanalysis-buildtasks-csc-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembl answers your question.