# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to install an existing project in Dotnet core but I was getting the error

```html
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
 <!--<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>-->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Boilerplate.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.8.391" />
    <PackageReference Include="Captcha" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="linqtotwitter" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="3.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update these  from the NuGet Package Manager will fix your issue

```
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```